# Where's the `restart` method in weex's Android SDK?

Tags: android, weex

I'm using weex in my project. At some times I need to reinit the weex environment, and I can call `[WXSDKEngine restart]` to achieve this easily in iOS.
I still have to do the same in Android, but I can't find a similar method in Android weex SDK. The methods I have tried are listed as below:

```
WXBridgeManager.restart();    
WXSDKEngine.reload();
WXSDKEngine.restartBridge;
```

None of them works as I expected.
Does weex Android SDK have a method like iOS's `[WXSDKEngine restart]`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reload` method:
`WXSDKEngine.reload();`